# Get return value from function call within lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq

Consider the following C# line:

```
var item = listOfItems.FirstOrDefault(i => GetResult(i) <= upperLimit);
```

My question is, is there a way of getting the return value of `GetResult(i)` from within that line?

The obvious answer is have two lines:

```
var item = listOfItems.FirstOrDefault(i => GetResult(i) <= upperLimit);
var result = GetResult(item);
```

But it seems a bit inefficient to call the same function twice... Is a way have the `result` with just one call?

Comment: Try this : var item = listOfItems.Where(i => GetResult(i) <= upperLimit).Select(j => GetResult(j)).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: @jdweng it looks like this will still invoke `GetResult` twice, based off of the generated IL.

Comment: @colmde depending on the cost of `GetResult`, your biggest issue may not be calling `GetResult` twice for a match, but rather the fact that you also call it for anything that is NOT a match.

Comment: @DavidL - will it not stop when it finds the first match?

Comment: @colmde it will, but what if the first match is the last item in the list?

Comment: Linq isn't always efficient, so if you really want optimal code don't use linq.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this (assuming `GetResult` returns an `int`):

```
int? result = null;
var item = listOfItems.FirstOrDefault(x => (result = GetResult(x)) <= upperLimit);
```

---

This solution will keep the *lazyness* of `FirstOrDefault` : it will stop at first match found.

Answer (score 2):

You can select both the item and the result of invoking `GetResult` on the item in an anonymous type to get them both like this:

```
var itemAndResult = listOfItems
    .Select(x => new {Item = x, Result = GetResult(x)})
    .Where(a => a.Result <= upperLimit)
    .FirstOrDefault();

var item = itemAndResult.Item;
var result = itemAndResult.Result;
```